# Why does my RPi UART0 (ttyAMA0) freezes when bluetooth disabled?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, debian-buster

I have a raspberry pi 3 model b (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)) and I want to disable the Bluetooth module connected to UART0 (pins 8 and 10) to make use of UART0. When I add the `dtoverlay=disable-bt` to the end of /boot/config.txt and connect a UART device, the raspberry pi freezes or signs me out.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this may be happening?

I have uninstalled the application that uses Bluetooth as well.
I've ran the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart.service
sudo systemctl disable bluealsa.service
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
```

My `/boot/config.txt`b file looks like this:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

# Enable UART
enable_uart=1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check dmesg for any signs of what could be going wrong, but dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt is what my line in on a pi3 that's working, so try add the pi3- to your line instead of just dtoverlay=disable-bt.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out that the pi didnt like when i wrote dtoverlay = pi3-disable-bt (with the extra spaces). Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that adding unnecessary spaces in the `/boot/config.txt` was causing my error.

I had written:

```
dtoverlay = disable-bt
```

instead of:

```
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

Also, it helped to go to `Pi > Preferences > RPi Configurations > Interfaces` to make sure that the serial ports were enabled.